# PHP Wordpress Form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I don't know what the heck the problem is with this form not working. The form is not to be sent anywhere. It's just a questionnaire for clients to fill/print out if they like, but I cannot get the results to post into the hidden div. What am I doing wrong? I installed a wordpress php plugin and other php echo's work, but not the POST thing. The HTML:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="yourname" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pet's Name" name="petsname" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pet's Birth Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date" name="petsbirthdate" />
    <br /><br />
    <strong>Pet's Sex</strong>: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="Male" name="sex" id="Male" /><label for="Male">Male</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" value="Female" name="sex" id="Female" /><label for="Female">Female</label>
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="show_output();">Display 
Answers</button>
</form>
```

Pay no attention to the onclick handler on the button. I'm not including that JavaScript, but just know that the hidden div does show when the button is clicked. The PHP that returns no form results: Pay no attention to the PHP in brackets, that's the way it works in WordPress with the plugin.

```
<p class="data_answers">
    <strong>Your Name:</strong> [php]echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['yourname']);[/php]</p>
<p class="data_answers">
    <strong>Pet's Name:</strong> [php]echo $_POST['petsname'];[/php]</p>
<p class="data_answers">
    <strong>Pet's Birth Date:</strong> [php]echo $_POST['petsbirthdate'];[/php]</p>
<p class="data_answers">
    <strong>Pet's Sex:</strong> [php]echo $_POST['sex'];[/php]</p>
```

The PHP that will work (anywhere; I even placed it in the middle of, where the form answers should be, and it shows up. So why doesn't the other work?

```
[php] echo "Hello world!"; [/php]
```

Thank You!
Tracy

P.S. Although you cannot see the PHP, but the actual page in draft is here: http://www.safarivet.com/behavior-conditions/

Comment: You've written the PHP tags as `[php]`, but to write PHP code inline in html you write `<?php echo 'TEST'; ?>`. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post above: Pay no attention to the PHP in brackets, that's the way it works in WordPress with the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `action` attribute in the `form` tag

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

..leads back to the same page

Comment: From what I have extensively read, you should NOT have an empty action tag. With it omitted, it validates and leads back to the same page as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from Johannes answer, you can also use a number sign `#` or the global variable `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Either of these will work

```
<form method="post" action"">

<form method="post" action"#">

<form method="post" action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Comment: No, no, no to all. I have read a kazillion pages and the best validating method in use Today is NO action attribute at all if you want it to lead back to the same page. Besides, tried all that anyway. Without the action, I don't have page reload issues.